# Como filtrar datos para esta eliminación?

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo un problema estoy intentando eliminar en una importacion, los post que tengo solo con el nombre "sugerencias" pero no he tenido buenos resultado

```
function my_delete_records() {
  $allposts= get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'qode-restaurant-menu',
    'numberposts'=>-1
  ));
  foreach ($allpost as $eachpost=>$sugerencias) {
    wp_delete_post( $eachpost->Id, true );
  }
}
```

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado específica de wordpress. Los que no lo usamos no sabemos lo que hacen ni como son las funciones get_post o wp_delete_post. Quizás deberás redirigir tu pregunta a algún sitio donde la temática sea wordpress.

Comment: nombre es el `post_name`, slug o parte del título? podrías incluir la data de importación? puede que sea mejor filtrar lo importado que borrar despues

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($POST as $campo => $valor){
    if ($campo == 'sugerencias'){
     wp_delete_post($valor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer]. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._